# Problem with building count down timer in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, countdown

I was trying to build a count down timer using VBA, and the result can be dynamically output to an Excel cell. I let procedure abc and def recursively call each other (did not set a stop point just for testing), and it worked. However, later with this exact same code I ran again, it failed, and error message was:

> Code execution has been interrupted.

Just can't figure out why, I didn't change anything, how could it work and then fail?

I tried `On Error Resume Next` and `Application.DisplayAlert = False`, both don't stop the error message popping up and the interruption of the code execution. And if I step through the procedures, it seems fine...

Also I wish to add a dynamic text like "start in how many seconds" like in the comment in another cell. Can it be realized in this way?

Thank you!

```
Sub abc()

    [a1] = [a1] - 1
    ' [a2] = "Start in " & [a1] & " seconds."
    Call def

End Sub


Sub def()

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    Call abc

End Sub
```

Comment: I would go with [Application.OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime) rather than trying to do something recursively (with concerns about the call stack).

Comment: Like Andy mentions, using `Application.Wait` is holding you back since it locks everything down while it runs. [This site has an interesting implementation](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/timer-stopwatch-excel-vba) that includes `DoEvents` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to do this recursively, with concerns about the call stack, I would use [Application.OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime).

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Call MyTimer

End Sub

Sub MyTimer()
    [a1] = [a1] - 1

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "MyTimer"
End Sub
```

I suppose this is still 'recursive' in a fashion, but the procedure exits each time. Only after 1 second has elapsed does it execute the procedure again.

But, either way, you should include some means of stopping the process. For example,

```
Sub MyTimer()
    [a1] = [a1] - 1

    If [a1] > 0 Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "MyTimer"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I realized that the reason why my code first worked and then failed must have something to do with "call stack" you mentioned, although I'm not exactly sure what does it mean, but I feel it's like something is taking up the memory that kind of stuff, because when I try to run my other program, it also return the error message of interruption! So what exactly did my countdown program do in the background so that caused this problem?

Comment: Roughly, each time a procedure is called some space/ data structure is allocated for it to store its state; think about this as storing local variables. Because the procedure calls itself, another such block is created, and another. Until the whole sequence exits (unwinds) this storage accumulates, potentially leading to a *stack overflow*. OnTime avoids this because the procedure exits each time; it just calls it again after a second.

Comment: "Code execution has been interrupted.", though, suggests that the code was interrupted by pressing Stop or Ctrl-Break, rather than indicating a problem with the stack. (You would have to interrupt it because you don't have an escape clause.)

Comment: Thank you so much! So did you mean that in the MyTimer sub, as soon as Application.OnTime is executed, the sub ends because it takes far less than a second for the program to reach and execute the End Sub line, and computer only needs to allocate space for one program actually. So in other word, suppose the time interval assigned to OnTime is smaller than it takes to run the rest of the code until End Sub is reaches, then it will recursively call the other Sub and cause call stack problem again? If I understood correctly?

Comment: I also tried within one Sub to add Application.wait inside a Do While Loop, but also return the execution was interrupted error message, not quite understand what is it now in this case where there’s only one Sub, so shouldn’t be call stack, just try to “slow down” the loop.

Comment: And in a scenario for example, now it is 4:55pm and I wish to count down to 5pm, and also at 5pm to run another VBA program using another Application.OnTime. I’m concern that at exactly 5pm, there will be two programs running, because the timer will have say Now is 4:59:59, so plus TimeValue(“00:00:01”) will then make it 5pm. Will there actually be any conflict? I heard that only one program can be run at a time. Also, how to cancel manually before the timer reaches the end? I tried clicking the stop button in VBE both inside Timer Sub and Button1_Click Sub, but the countdown just don’t stop.

Comment: And you mentioned that until the whole sequence exits this storage accumulates, so is there any way to release the space/ data structure without a reboot? Even after I closed Excel and reopen, my other program still couldn’t be run, I have to log off. Shouldn’t everything be emptied and released after Sub is ended? Sorry for these many questions.

Comment: Application.OnTime sets Excel to do something when the time arises. This instruction then no longer has anything to do with the current procedure that is running. It has no influence on when the current procedure exits or its stack is cleared. [Well, I suppose that is not entirely accurate, because the time could arise before the procedure exits.] Anyway, extended secondary discussions are not encouraged in the forum.

Comment: Alright, so just wanted to ask to turn off the timer manually before it reaches 0, do I just add “False” to the command: Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "MyTimer"? Thanks!

Comment: Set what to false??! Not sure where you got that from. My added code in the answer stops setting OnTime when the value reaches 0, so nothing further will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire code is working fine for me (also including the `[a2]` part). I'm on Windows 7 with Excel 2013.

I suggest you include a stopping condition to `abc()` like

```
If [a1] > 0 Then
   Call def
End If
```

Please provide some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a function btw? Does it work for you?

```
Function wait(seconds As Long)

    Dim originalStatusBar As String, i As Long
    originalStatusBar = Application.StatusBar

    For i = seconds To 0 Step -1
        Application.wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Application.StatusBar = "Start in " & i & " seconds"
    Next

    Application.StatusBar = originalStatusBar

End Function
```

Then in your sub you just call it like so:

```
wait 5 'waits 5 seconds and updates status bar with remaining time
```

or

```
wait [a1]-1
```